# Variable in Namespace for ElasticBeanstalk CFT

Tags: yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template yml file that passes OptionSettings for an ElasticBeanstalk applicaiton. I can hard code values, and I can pass values from Parameters. However, I am unable to determine how to pass Parameters or Variables as the namespace.

This works:

```
   - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:lbtargetgroup
     OptionName: Port
     Value: 3000
```

This works (where PORTNUMBER is a parameter)

```
Parameters:
  PORTNUMBER:
    Type: String
    Description: Port number

ElasticBeanstalkConfig:
  Properties:
    OptionSettings:
    - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:lbtargetgroup
      OptionName: Port
      Value: !Ref PORTNUMBER
```

However, this does not work (where LBTARGETGROUP is a parameter):

```
Parameters:
  LBTARGETGROUP:
    Type: String
    Description: Target Group Name

ElasticBeanstalkConfig:
  Properties:
    OptionSettings:
    - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:!Ref LBTARGETGROUP
      OptionName: Port
      Value: 3000
```

From what I have tried, you cannot use typical Variables in a CFT (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html#template-anatomy-sections). I have also tried mappings. But I can't seem to figure out how to pass the name as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is often very simple... the following works:

```
Parameters:
  LBTARGETGROUP:
    Type: String
    Description: Target Group Name

ElasticBeanstalkConfig:
  Properties:
    OptionSettings:
    - Namespace: !Join ["", ["aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:", Ref: LBTARGETGROUP]]
      OptionName: Port
      Value: 3000
```